# pyqt4 problems with resorce system (TypeError: qRegisterResourceData)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

When I run this code (which I created a module for my qrc file)

```
import sys                              
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

mainwindow = uic.loadUiType("mainmenu2.ui")[0] #load the UI
class Mainmenu(QtGui.QMainWindow, mainwindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mainmenu, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #self.aboutp.clicked.connect(self.linkabout)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = Mainmenu
#aboutwindow = About_us_page(None)
mainwindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\megan\Desktop\newqt\try1.py", line 7, in <module>
    mainwindow = uic.loadUiType("mainmenu2.ui")[0] #load the UI   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\__init__.py", line 211, in loadUiType
    exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)   File "<string>", line 202, in <module>   File "C:\Users\megan\Desktop\newqt\test_rc.py", line 49680, in <module>
    qInitResources()   File "C:\Users\megan\Desktop\newqt\test_rc.py", line 49675, in qInitResources
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data) TypeError: qRegisterResourceData(int, str, str, str): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str`'
```

so I know the problem is in my resource file, and I've looked online and the only help I could find was this comment

```
pyrcc generates Python 2.x code by default.
Try regenerating your resource files using pyrcc with flag '-py3'
```

But I don't know how to do that so please if someone could help me solve this problem, thanks

Comment: How do you generate the `test_rc.py`?

Comment: I created an empty notepad file and saved it as test.qrc, I then created it into a py module

Comment: You say *I then created it into a py module*, how do you convert that .qrc to .py?

Comment: by  putting this code pyrcc4 test.qrc -o test_rc.py into command prompt

Comment: execute: `pyrcc4 test.qrc -o test_rc.py -py3`

Comment: Thank you but now I get this error TypeError: QWidget.show(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'

Comment: Chance Mainmenu to Mainmenu()

Comment: Thank you so much -btw I can now finish my a level project

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell or the cmd go to the directory where the resource file is stored and run:

```
`pyrcc4 resource.qrc -o resource_rc.py -py3`
```